# Unable to link site to Android app through the Digital Assets Link protocol

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, digital-assets-links

I have completed successfully all the steps required in the `App Link Assistant` in the `Android Studio` like suggested in answers to other questions about this subject:
[image]

But I'm still unable to upload an `Instant App` to testing. I get the following error:

> Error
>   Your site 'mydomain' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.

The `assetlinks.json` is available under `https://mydomain/.well-known` and looks like this:

`[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "appId",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["key"]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://mydomain"
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "appId",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["key"]
  }
}]`

And I've added the following to the relevant `Activity` in the `Manifest`:

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mydomain"
                />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: there are a couple of similar posts floating around and revolve around: 1. you used the wrong key (upload vs signing), 2. https is not accessible, 3. wait 24hrs after assetlinks changes

Comment: I have started the question with the results from App Link Assistant because that means that I am using the right key and https is accessible and everything else I could find in any of the other posts is already covered.

Comment: Yes, but that helper only checks what you have provided, your fingerprint could still be incorrect. Otherwise, you can submit your issue to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 and they'll investigate it if you provide your manifest files.